# URL is not passing in cross browser testing code selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

i am trying to write code for testing on two, chrome and Firefox browser, both browser gets open but the URL is not getting passed in that.
need help to work further, thank in advance.

```
WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")

    public void setup(String browser) throws Exception {

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.manage().window().maximize();

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\disha.shah/myWork/eclipse/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.manage().window().maximize();


        } else {
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");

        }

        // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test
    @Parameters({ "username", "password" })
    public void login(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException {

        driver.get("url goes here");
        driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    }
}
```

Here is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Sample Test Suite" verbose="3" thread-count="2"
    parallel="methods">
    <test name="ChromeTest">

        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testngDemo.Login">
                <methods>
                    <include name="setup"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>

    </test>

    <test name="FirefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testngDemo.Login">
                <methods>
                    <include name="setup"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Login Test">
        <parameter name="username" value="dishashah" />
        <parameter name="password" value="disha1234" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testngDemo.Login">
                <methods>
                    <include name="login"></include>

                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: can any one tell me plz

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the testng.xml file. I've made some changes to above testng.xml file.
[see the updated xml here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj0yj.png)

Comment: Yes.. we can also place the parameter tag below the suite tag. Please see the xml here http://imgur.com/vy73sQs

Comment: but what if there are many methods and their parameters.., all the parameters i need to pass in this way only in XML?

Comment: I guess if we want to pass parameters from testNG xml file then these are two ways that we can do. Please vote the this answer if it answers your question.